# Cannot connect SSAS Server to Power BI

Tags: ssas, powerbi-desktop, olap-cube

I would like to connect my cube from SSAS to Power BI Desktop (Direct connection) but I can't access to the server of SSAS.. I get this: "The server you are trying to connect to does not have templates or you do not have permission to access it"

I tried also the import option and I manage to connect to the server but I can't select the cube..
I googled about this issue but none of solutions I found worked for me
Any suggestions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For those who are faced the same problem, just add the name of the database..it's worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).